# Ran route -f on AWS Windows server and now can't reconnect

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-web-services

I was attempting to resolve a network issue on an AWS server and while in an RDP session, stupidly ran 'route -f' and now am unable to reconnect to the server at all. It's gone completely dark. AWS shows it is running but I don't know how to recover access. How screwed am I? How can I get connected to this server to resolve the issues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it! I ran a combo of the EC2 Repairs for non-managed systems in AWS. Specifically, I believe AWSSupport-TroubleshootRDP resolved it. I am counting my lucky stars it wasn't going to be a much more manual process.

Comment: Great :) Don't forget to take backups / snapshots before making configuration changes in future :)